# Visual Studio Breakpoint Warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

When debugging my code, I often throw breakpoints in to check the values of local variables to make sure everything is on the right track.

Lately, when I make changes to my code and recompile, all my breakpoints turn into the outline of a circle (instead of a full red circle) and it gives me an error that reads;

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is
>   associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional
>   compilation or complier optimizations.

What's strange about this issue is that I can simply remove and add the breakpoint and everything will work completely fine.

I am not using any type of conditional compilation or complier optimizations. Does anyone know what this means or how to fix this? It gets quite annoying replacing 10-12 breakpoints each time I compile.

Comment: What type of project are you building?

Comment: @forsvarir: The solution consists of a class library and a windows application to test it. The breakpoint problem happens in either project.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling in debug mode? Also check the project properties to see if debug symbols are defined and make sure you don't check the code optimization option.

Comment: You've presumably tried doing clean builds and the problem still comes back?  When you're readding the breakpoints is it before the program is running, or after you've started it?

Comment: @BrunoLM: The solution is currently compiling in debug mode, debug symbols are defined and do work if I re-insert them after compiling, and code optimization is unchecked.

Comment: @forsvarir: A clean build does not seem to work. To readd the breakpoints I do it before I run the program, adding them at runtime does not work and gives me the above error.

Comment: we can also set 'use multi byte encoding' in the project configuration properties

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can happen for a few reasons

- The code the debugger is using is different from the code that the application is running
- The pdb file that the debugger is using is different from the code that the application is running
- The code the application is running has been optimized and debug information has been stripped out.
- The code in which you have breakpoints on hasn't been loaded into the process yet (assuming the things above are not the culprits)
- If you are attaching the debugger, pay attention to what .net framework it's attaching to (i've had issues with it using .net 4 when code was all .net 2.0)
- The assembly you have is also in the GAC. This might happen if say you installed your program so you could debug it, but the installer put the dll in the GAC.
- Remove the reference and re-add it (thanks to [forsvarir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592182/forsvarir)). Typically this occurs when the project that is referenced is not in the solution, and VS will copy the dll from the bin directory of another project. You will know this was the issue when you try to re-add the reference, and can't find the project :)

It's pretty tough to figure out what's going on here, but i would suggest using the fusion log viewer to see what is being loaded and where it's being loaded from and then you can look at the dll and see if it's old code, etc.

Comment: The dll is being referenced through the project so the library gets complied every time and it updates the reference on each build. I cannot say that I am sure that all the above bullets are not true but is this a common case?

Comment: it can be. i've seen the issue before where the dll was referenced by the project, but not copied to the output directory because no code actually used anything from the dll (basically implementation code that was being injected by IoC). to check to make sure the dll is being copied is right, go the the output directory (ie bin\debug) and delete everything from there and rebuild. if it's copied then that part is fine.

Comment: added another issue i've seen before regarding gac. perhaps a bit more info in the question could help the issue be pinpointed sooner.

Comment: Another, related thing that can help resolve some issues is removing the project references and adding them back in again, although since Kyle is reporting the problem in the main exe as well as in libraries, that's probably not going to help in this case :0)

Comment: It's always worth checking debugger options under Tools->Options->Debugger->General. Some options are required for proper debugging (e.g. Use Managed Compatibility Mode for C++/CLI applications).

Comment: Thx, Add one more point. If any new key is added in web config and set in static variable then static class will not intialize properly

Answer (score 8):

### Check the project settings

Make sure you don't check the code optimize option, and make sure debug symbols are checked.

[image: debug]

Notice that when you change the configuration other settings might change as well and you might not see. Make sure the values are correct for the configuration you are attempting to compile.

---

### Delete the output files

Physically delete all generated DLLs, PDBs and EXEs. Then compile again to generate the files. Sometimes Visual Studio can "get lost" and "forget" to overwrite the output files when you build your solution.

---

### Restart your computer

It usually solves 99% of problems. I already had some issues with Visual Studio and restarting it or the computer solved the problem.

Comment: My settings reflect the picture above 100%. These were the first settings I checked.

Comment: @Kyle did you try restarting your computer? Seriously, I already had some issues with VS that I had to restart my computer so it could go back to normal. With TFS mainly.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but still timely enough as I was looking for any other reason I might be getting this problem.

That being said you also might want to check the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" in your c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\[Frameworks] directories if you are creating a web application as these files are often the cause in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the precompiler directive #line appears to affect the breakpoints behavior as well, as I've just discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this response to the old thread in case someone like me is tracking down this mystery in an older ASP.Net application. I had one Webform code-behind which did not respond to breakpoints with the "...no executable code..." debugger warning. It was doing my head in as all of the other pages were working fine. I'd done the clean, rebuild, purged the temporary ASP.Net files, no joy.

The culprit with this file was the inclusion of several #ExternalSource directives surrounding some of the member variable declarations. Once those were removed and the project rebuilt, the break point behavior was restored. Those ExternalSource lines were appearing in the generated section of the code-behind. Not sure why they were there.