# No executable code associated with line. Point class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am doing a very simple operation (initializing the Point variable in C++).

```
Point leftEye = Point(-1,-1);
```

But when I run code it simply passes through it even without touching it. So I can't see this variable in locals of my debugger and breakpoint states next caution: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line. ..."
Could anyone give any idea why is this happening. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Pro.
Thanks.

Comment: Depending on how it is used it could be optimized away.  Do you have optimizations on?

Comment: @user3851668 Try to run in `Debug` mode. See also [Visual Studio Breakpoint Warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100871/visual-studio-breakpoint-warning)

Comment: @NathanOliver No, I have all the optimizations off. "Disabled (/Od)"

Comment: @tchelidze Just checked out in Debug and it works. But why is this happening and how can I make it working in release? Thank you in advance.

Comment: More than likely there is a setting in your release build that allows the compile to skip it or reorder it.  Can you post an [mcve]?

Comment: @user3851668 As it was already mentioned, In release (by default) code [is optimized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113866/what-does-optimize-code-option-really-do-in-visual-studio) . you can disable code optimization Go to `Project -> Properties -> Build` choose `Configuration` as `Release` and untick `Optimize Code` option.