# The breakpoint will not currently be hit - No executable code is associated with this line

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-debugging

I have a problem to debug my ASP.NET Core 2 application. Suddenly all breakpoints in application cannot be hit.

The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target is associated with this line.

The message in tooltip on breakpoint after debugging start is:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation or complier optimizations, or the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current debugger code type.

Comment: It's not the same. The problem is: "No executable code of the debugger's target is associated with this line." But why?

Comment: oh my bad, did check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100871/visual-studio-breakpoint-warning)?

Comment: Thanks, I tried all from the list of possible issues before, but nothing helps :-(

Comment: I faced the same issue before and my solution was I cleaned the project from `build` menu and than changed the configuration in visual studio from `release` to `debug`. Give it a try

Comment: Same situation after cleaned the project.

Comment: @eridanix, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: Same problem here (asp.net core). I have tried anything I find - nothing has worked (It's very annoying to develop a web app without working debugger). @eridanix: I DON'T think, that the clean has solved your problem...? Have you solved your problem - if yes - how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solutions in my case was to change build properties of the project.

Project properties -> Build -> Advanced (button) - Debugging information (select box) -> FULL.

Comment: While converting a two dozen project solution to SDK style csproj's and PackageReference's inside MVC3-5 csproj's and had one odd library in the middle that would not allow breakpoints to be set. Changing the debugging information to full for that project took care of it.

Comment: This worked for me. Not sure why my breakpoints stopped being hit in the first place, but this did the trick.

Comment: This was my problem

Answer (score 5):

The solutions above did not work for me on VS 2019 Version 16.8.3 targeting Core 3.1 or Net5. I cannot get breakpoints to work on JaveScript in *.cshtml files. Breakpoints set on Razor script does work in .cshtml though. For JS, the only workaround I've found is moving Java Script to .js files. The breakpoints work in *.js files as expected - for me anyway.

Comment: This was certainly the most helpful comment for me using the latest visual studio in Feb 2021 - I ended up giving up the rabbit trail of trying to deal with the issue after hours of struggling, and just put the breakpoint in my js files.

Answer (score 0):

@eridanix has the right solution however if you are using VS code or editing the project file by hand you can insert the following into the project file XML, which is what selecting the FULL option via the GUI is doing.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you need the full PDB for other configurations you will need to add those as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

There's a maximum of 65535 characters in a line of code.  (I had serialized a file for testing purposes into one line).  If you exceed this line length, you'll get this error.   I also went the route "repair" and that didn't work.  I'm using VS 2017, C#, ASP.Net Core 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had to Enable Script Debugging in the Debug DropDown?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET. Check here:
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET